# What is the correct method to read from a NetworkStream?

Tags: c#, server, networkstream

I'm developing a software that will constantly receive requests of various types and different lengths.

In particular, the `length` is the part that interest me because I don't know the length of the message that I will go to receive.

For the moment I wrote this code that goes to write the received bytes in a `byte[]` of a very large size, and then copies in a second `byte[]` only the length of the data.

```
//get the network stream
NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

//initialize an bytes array of size 5 MB
byte[] largeArray = new byte[5242880];

//write the bytes in the largeArray
//determines the length of the received message
int lenght = networkStream.Read(largeArray, 0, largeArray.Length);

//initialize an bytes array with the correct message length
byte[] messageArray = new byte[lenght];

//make a copy from the largeArray to the messageArray with the right lenght
Buffer.BlockCopy(largeArray, 0, messageArray, 0, messageArray.Length);
```

I wanted to know if this method can be corrected or are there better alternatives to receive messages of unknown lengths ?

Comment: TCP/IP is not a message-based protocol, making this approach inherently flawed. A `NetworkStream` will read as many bytes as happen to be available in the network buffers, which may be less than a message or more than one message. Worse, the number of bytes returned bears no relation to the length of your messages. If your messages have a fixed length, you have to include that length in the transmission. Stephen Cleary has a nice [article](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html) about this (including sample code for how to do it right).

Comment: As a follow-up to that, the Serious People who have Serious Demands on the scalability of code (mainly those writing servers that process thousands of requests from as many different clients) are writing even more complex code, and APIs to simplify that back again -- that's what [System.IO.Pipelines](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/07/09/system-io-pipelines-high-performance-io-in-net/) is about. You don't need to start off with that, though, since most servers won't be called on to perform to such levels. Message framing can be as simple as reading lengths from a `BufferedStream`.